# Dagger field injection and entry points

Tags: dependency-injection, dagger

I am trying dagger in one of my projects and i am experiencing this situation:
"Field injection only works if I declare the class as an entry point in the module definition."

Is this the correct behaviour?

The below dependencies are not injected to Messenger class if Messenger.class is not declared as an entry point. Constructor injector works fine but I don't want to declare a multi parameter constructor.

```java
public class Messenger implements NetworkInterfaceListener {
  @Inject public NetworkInterface networkInterface;
  @Inject public MessageFactoryInterface messageFactory;
  @Inject public Bus bus;
  @Inject public Logger log;
  ...
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have only two alternatives: either to declare injectable constructor with all params to be injected or enlist class into `entryPoints` (now called `injects`) of your dagger module and call `mGraph.inject(this)` in default constructor (or whenever you need to actually "inject" maybe even outside the class).

Comment: Also, according to the [`dagger`](http://square.github.io/dagger/) site, "If your module's bindings will be used outside of the listed injects then mark the module as a library", using the `@Module(library = true)` annotation